# React Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am currently working on the final project of a coding Bootcamp and there's just one thing that I can't seem to figure out(not sure if it is possible though).

I have a list of activities, where I map every activity into a card (which works fine). Now I would like to put these cards into the React Bootstrap Carousel and show 4 cards at a time. When I press one of the indicator it should slide to the next (or previous) card (not the next 4 cards). The only thing that I can get to work is having 1 card in the carousel.

Hoping that there is someone out there who is able to help me out.

Thank you from a nonDeveloper to a soon to become noobDeveloper.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Cardslider.css";
import Explorecard from "./Explorecard/Explorecard";
import axios from "axios";
import Carousel from "react-bootstrap/Carousel";

function createCard(area) {
  return (
    <Carousel.Item>
      <div>
        <Explorecard image={`images/${area.area}.jpg`} title={area.area} />
      </div>
    </Carousel.Item>
  );
}

const Cardslider = (props) => {
  const [listOfActivities, setListOfActivities] = useState([]);

  const getAllActivities = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:9999/activities")
      .then((responseFromApi) => {
        console.log(responseFromApi);
        setListOfActivities(responseFromApi.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };

  useEffect(getAllActivities, []);

  return (
    <div className="cards-container">
      <Carousel className="explore-card-carousel" indicators={false}>
        {listOfActivities.map(createCard)}
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cardslider;
```

Comment: at the start all the 4 cards are showing, and after you click then only one is showing? or from the beggining just one is there?

Comment: Only one card is showing. I want it to show 4 cards at the same time.

Comment: i think its wierde. may try to log `listOfActivities.map(createCard)` and look if there are 4 cards. if yes, look in the elements of the DOM and  look if there are 4 cards. if yes, i dont know :)

Comment: Unfortunately it only shows 1 card.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the Carousel.Item tag, you must use the Carousel tag.

Comment: Updating your answer with some sample code would be helpful in this case, it would better illustrate your point since it looks like OP is already doing this.